# What happened to the new kid's parents after the end of South Park: The Fractured But Whole?

Tags: south-park-the-fractured-but-whole

What happened to the new kid's parents after the end of *South Park: The Fractured But Whole*?

After the end of the game, his parents are nowhere to be found anymore. Are they really dead? Or are they still alive in another dimension?

Answer (score 2):

There's a cutscene implying they go off to have sex after your time farts bring everything back. Though they do disappear from the game after that, you can walk into their room, which is empty. Can't seem to find them in the town after searching for myself.